# Python relative path simplifier

Tags: python, windows, path

I am having issues with paths, hitting the Windows' restriction on the number of characters in the path at 256.

In some place in my python script the 2 paths are getting appended and they both are relative paths, and these become very long:

e.g.:

```
path1 = "..\\..\\..\\..\\..\\..\\..\\Source/lib/Target/abcd/abc_def_ghf/source/zzzModule/"
path2 = "../../../../../../../../Source/directory/Common/headerFile.h"
```

Appended path:

```
path3 = "..\\..\\..\\..\\..\\..\\..\\Source/lib/Target/abcd/abc_def_ghf/source/zzzModule/../../../../../../../../Source/directory/Common/headerFile.h"
```

And `path3` is passed in my Visual Studio solution. At this point VS stops and says that the file is not found.

The observation here is that the final `path3` goes 7 levels up then 7 levels down and then again 8 levels up. Is there any utility in python which will take this and generate a simplified relative path for me?

e.g.

```
some_utility(path3) = "../../../../../../../../Source/directory/Common/headerFile.h"
```

I know I can write a utility myself but I am just checking if there is any. If there is some it will save my 20 minutes of coding.

Comment: Googling for *python path normalize* brings answer in the first link – http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html‎

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost : I dodn't know that it is called path normalization. I had searched for "Python relative path optimization" but the results didn't help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [os.path.normpath](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath) to resolve `..` in the path:

```
In [93]: os.path.normpath(os.path.join(path1,path2))
Out[93]: '../Source/directory/Common/headerFile.h'
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `os.path.normpath` (+1 @unutbu), but just for fun, here's a way to do it manually:

```
def normpath(path3):
    path = path3.split('/')  # or use os.path.sep
    answer = []
    for p in path:
        if p != '..':
            answer.append(p)
        else:
            if all(a=='..' for a in answer):
                answer.append(p)
            else:
                answer.pop()
    return '/'.join(answer)
```

And the output:

```
In [41]: normpath("../../../../../../../Source/lib/Target/abcd/abc_def_ghf/source/zzzModule/../../../../../../../../Source/directory/Common/headerFile.h")
Out[41]: '../../../../../../../../Source/directory/Common/headerFile.h'
```

Comment: This misses some important edgecases; windows paths can start with `\\.\` or `\\?\`, which must be preserved unchanged, you can have UNC paths (start with `//machine/mountpoint/...`) and you can have drive letters (`C:/...`), and you are not processing `./` elements (current directory). You also want to use `path3.replace('\\', '/')` to handle either forward or backward slashes the same.